# Creating a right side menu on C++ using openGL

Tags: c++, opengl, menu, paint

I'm working on a project that is creating a painting program using OpenGL and GLUT on C++.

So far I have a color menu on the left side and now I am trying to make a tool menu on the right side but I can't figure out how to get it on the right.

This is what i have so far:

```
int inwindow(int x, int y)
{
    return (x > WLEFT && x < WRIGHT && y > WBOTTOM && y < WTOP);
}

static float colormenu[][8] = {{Red}, {Orange}, {Yellow}, {Green}, {Cyan}, {Blue}, {Purple}, {Black}};

int incolormenu(int x, int y)
{
    return (x >= 0 && x <= MENUWIDTH && y >= 0 && y <= HEIGHT);
}

int colormenuindex(int x, int y)
{
    if(!incolormenu(x, y))
        return -1;
    else
        return(y / BOXHEIGHT);
}


static float toolmenu[][6] = {{Pencil}, {Line}, {Box}, {Rectangle}, {Circle}, {FCircle}};

int intoolmenu(int x, int y)
{
    return (x >= 0 && x <= MENUWIDTH && y >= 0 && y <= HEIGHT);
}

int toolmenuindex(int x, int y)
{
    if(!intoolmenu(x, y))
        return -1;
    else
        return(y / BOXHEIGHT);
}

void drawSketch()
{
    int i;

    glClearColor(Grey, 1);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glColor3f(Black);

    for(i = 0; i < NCOLORS; i++)
    {
        glColor3f(colormenu[i][R], colormenu[i][G], colormenu[i][B]);
        glRecti(1, BOXHEIGHT * i + 1, MENUWIDTH - 1, BOXHEIGHT * (i + 1) - 1);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < NCOLORS; i++)
    {
        glColor3f(toolmenu[i][Pencil], toolmenu[i][Line], toolmenu[i][Box]);
        glRasterPos3f(0.2, -0.8, -1.5);
    }

    glFlush();
}
```

Comment: What `glRasterPos3f` is supposed to do in this case?

Comment: What are R, G and B in first `glColor3f`? And why are you calling second one using some non-related values? What outcome you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are willing to use a third party solution but I've used the following project with really good results.

[NanoGUI Github Project](https://github.com/wjakob/nanogui)